# Bug? Jackson Object mapper adds object at the end of Objectlist

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson, objectmapper

My application has an object GameCards, that contains a card-deck ( shuffled, based on two normal card decks).
I store it as a string, via a converter that calls jackson objectMapper.

The object before I store it looks like this:

```
[gameDeck=[Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_8], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=vrouw], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=heer], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_5], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_9], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=boer], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_3], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_4], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=aas], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_4], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_3], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=heer], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_5], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_4], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_9], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_5], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_5], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_9], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_8], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=aas], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=aas], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=vrouw], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_2], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=vrouw], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_7], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_7], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_6], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_4], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=vrouw], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=boer], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=vrouw], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=boer], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_6], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_6], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_9], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=heer], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_7], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_2], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=boer], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_5], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=heer], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=aas], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_3], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_2], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_8], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_6], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_4], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=boer], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_8], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_8], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_3], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_7], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_7], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=vrouw], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=boer], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_5], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_6], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_2], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_4], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_2], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=vrouw], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_2], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_2], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=heer], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_7], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=_9], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_6], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=aas], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_4], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=heer], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_3], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=aas], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_3], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_6], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_5], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_8], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=aas], Card [kleur=harten, waarde=heer], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_8], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_8], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_5], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=_3], Card [kleur=klaver, waarde=_9], Card [kleur=ruiten, waarde=boer], Card [kleur=schoppen, waarde=_4]]]
```

it is converted into this json ( Note that an Object Card is added at the beginning ( actually the second card from the gameCards object is placed as a separste card before the gameCards Object... that should not be there ....):

```
{"card":{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"vrouw"},"gameCards":[{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_8"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"heer"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_5"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_9"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"boer"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_3"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_4"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"aas"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_4"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_3"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"heer"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_5"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_4"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_9"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_5"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_5"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_9"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_8"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"aas"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"aas"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"vrouw"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_2"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"vrouw"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_7"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_7"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_6"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_4"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"vrouw"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"boer"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"vrouw"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"boer"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_6"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_6"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_9"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"heer"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_7"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_2"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"boer"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_5"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"heer"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"aas"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_3"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_2"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_8"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_6"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_4"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"boer"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_8"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_8"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_3"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_7"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_7"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"vrouw"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"boer"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_5"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_6"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_2"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_4"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_2"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"vrouw"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_2"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_2"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"heer"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_7"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"_9"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_6"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"aas"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_4"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"heer"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_3"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"aas"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_3"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_6"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_5"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_8"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"aas"},{"kleur":"harten","waarde":"heer"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_8"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_8"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_5"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"_3"},{"kleur":"klaver","waarde":"_9"},{"kleur":"ruiten","waarde":"boer"},{"kleur":"schoppen","waarde":"_4"}]}
```

I use this converter. ( The println output is what I showed above.)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import nl.hu.bep2.casino.blackjack.domain.GameCards;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Converter
public class CardListConverter implements AttributeConverter<GameCards, String> {
    
    GameCards gameCards = new GameCards();
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(GameCards gameCards) {
        System.out.println("%%%%$$$$$%%%%%###############$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        System.out.println("CardListConverter to db is aangeroepen!!! voor gameCards " + gameCards);
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       
        String gameCardsJson = null;
        try {
            gameCardsJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(gameCards);
            
            System.out.println("dit maakt de mapper er van:" + gameCardsJson);
        } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println("CardListConverter To DB Kolom geeft error"+ e);
        }
        return gameCardsJson;
    }
      
    @Override
    public GameCards convertToEntityAttribute(String gameCardsJson) {
    
        // System.out.println("CardListConverter to Entity is aangeroepen!!! voor gameCardsJson " + gameCardsJson);
        if (gameCardsJson == null) {
            System.out.println("gameCardsJson is empty!!!");
        }
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       
        try {
            
            return  mapper.readValue(gameCardsJson, GameCards.class );
                
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            System.out.println("CardListConverter To Entity (from json) geeft error"+ e);
           
        }
    
        return null;
    }
}
```

Does anyone what goes wrong here?

The GameCards object:

```
public class GameCards implements Serializable {

    private List<Card> gameDeck = new ArrayList<>();  
    
    public GameCards() {
    }
    
    public GameCards(int numberOfDecks) {  
        
        this.gameDeck = GameCards.initiateDeck(numberOfDecks);
    }
    
    
    public static List<Card> initiateDeck(int numberOfDecks) {
        
        
        int loop =numberOfDecks;
        Kleur kleuren[] = Kleur.values();
        Waarde waarden[] = Waarde.values();
        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while (loop > 0) {
            
            for(Kleur kleur: kleuren) {
                if (kleur == Kleur.achterkant) {
                    continue;
                }
                for( Waarde waarde: waarden) {
                    if (waarde == Waarde.achterkant) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Card card = new Card(kleur, waarde);
                    cards.add(card);
                }
            }
            loop--;   // loop met één verlagen als er één compleet deck is toegevoegd
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
        return cards;
        
        
    }

    public  List<Card> getGameCards(){
        return this.gameDeck;
    }

    public Card getCard() {
        
        Card card = null; ;
        
        card = this.gameDeck.get(1); // kies de bovenste kaart van het geschudde deck
        this.gameDeck.remove(1);     //en verwijder deze uit de deck
        return card;                 //geef deze kaart aan bv een speler of dealer

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GameCards [gameDeck=" + gameDeck + "]";
    }
```

The card:

```
public class Card implements Serializable  {
   private Kleur kleur;
   private Waarde waarde;
   
   public Card() {
   }
   
   
   public Card(Kleur kleur, Waarde waarde) {
       this.kleur = kleur;
       this.waarde = waarde;
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   public Kleur getKleur() {
       return kleur;
   }

   public void setKleur(Kleur kleur) {
       this.kleur = kleur;
   }

   public Waarde getWaarde() {
       return waarde;
   }

   public void setWaarde(Waarde waarde) {
       this.waarde = waarde;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "Card [kleur=" + kleur + ", waarde=" + waarde + "]";
   }
   
   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectMapper scan your set and get methods. So you should not use method like getCards and getGameCards. Because of these methods your json is generated not correct. You must change your GameCards class like that.

```
public class GameCards implements Serializable {

private List<Card> gameDeck = new ArrayList<>();  

public GameCards() {
}

public GameCards(int numberOfDecks) {  
    
    this.gameDeck = GameCards.initiateDeck(numberOfDecks);
}


public static List<Card> initiateDeck(int numberOfDecks) {
    
    
    int loop =numberOfDecks;
    Kleur kleuren[] = Kleur.values();
    Waarde waarden[] = Waarde.values();
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while (loop > 0) {
        
        for(Kleur kleur: kleuren) {
            if (kleur == Kleur.achterkant) {
                continue;
            }
            for( Waarde waarde: waarden) {
                if (waarde == Waarde.achterkant) {
                    continue;
                }
                Card card = new Card(kleur, waarde);
                cards.add(card);
            }
        }
        loop--;   // loop met één verlagen als er één compleet deck is toegevoegd
    }
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
    return cards;
    
    
}

public  List<Card> getGameDeck(){
    return this.gameDeck;
}

public  void setGameDeck(){
    return this.gameDeck;
}

public Card pullCard() {
    
    Card card = null; ;
    
    card = this.gameDeck.get(1); // kies de bovenste kaart van het geschudde deck
    this.gameDeck.remove(1);     //en verwijder deze uit de deck
    return card;                 //geef deze kaart aan bv een speler of dealer

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "GameCards [gameDeck=" + gameDeck + "]";
}
```

}